# QT5.6 how to use new dock features?

Tags: c++, qdockwidget, qt5.6

http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/03/16/qt-5-6-released/ says:

> Our dock widget infrastructure has seen quite some improvements,
>   making it possible to programmatically resize docks, drop dock widgets
>   into floating docks and re-arrange tabbed docks.

I love docks and think they should be improved even more. However, I have not found out how I can programmatically resize docks. How can I do this? Also, what does "dropping dock widgets into floating docks" even mean? I have tried out the official example dock QT application but was not able to drop one dock widget into another, floating one.

Has anyone found any additional information to his amazingly sounding news?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#resizeDocks). I think that is what you are looking for. It is not as straightforward as you may have imagined though because of the nature of the docks (them being embedded in the `QMainWindow`).

Comment: Thanks, that is even better than what I hoped for because I can work with ratios that way. In addition, I found this helpful: https://woboq.com/blog/qdockwidget-changes-in-56.html